# select with multiple conditions,

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi guys

I am quite new for the SQL, this site as well.

I have data as below, i want to select all records except failure"BTM dead" for Train "1101", which means only the records 1, 3 will not be selected.

```
*record*     | *Train*    |  *Failure*     |

   1         |  1101      |   BTM dead     |
   2         |  1101      |  relay failure |
   3         |  1101      |   BTM dead     |
   4         |  2101      |  relay failure |
   5         |  2101      |   BTM dead     |
   6         |  2101      |  relay failure |
```

Here is what I tried..

```
SELECT failure_table.record, failure_table.Train, failure_table.Failure
FROM failure_table
WHERE failure_table.Train <> 1101 And failure_table.Failure <> "BTM dead";
```

but turns out that only records 4,6 selected.
can I have a suggestion on that please? what statement would it be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT failure_table.record, failure_table.Train, failure_table.Failure
FROM failure_table
WHERE NOT (failure_table.Train = 1101 And failure_table.Failure = 'BTM dead')
```

Sometimes the easiest way is to use NOT.

So because you know you want everything except when train = 1101 and failure = 'BTM' simply state that and then tell sql you want the opposite by saying NOT.  Also note you need single quotes when identifying a string not double quotes or it will think it is a column.

Comment: @WarawutNualplaud: if the answer is satisfactory for you, then you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking a thingie under the downvote button. This way it won't show in the unsolved questions, and it's going to be clear that there's nothing more to be added.

Answer (score 4):

You used `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
 SELECT failure_table.record, failure_table.Train, failure_table.Failure
 FROM failure_table
 WHERE failure_table.Train <> 1101 OR failure_table.Failure <> 'BTM dead';
```

Comment: this will select only 4,5 & 6

Comment: It's exactly the same thing as `Matt`'s answer, as per de Morgan's law

Comment: @jonju mszymborski is correct and the answer works because even though a train maybe 1101 it can also be <> to 'BTM dead' which means it would still be returned., I mistakingly down voted it myself not thinking enough through it so if mszymborski you edit your answer and change the " double quotes to single which is necessary, I will correct my mistake and up vote. and he is also correct on morgan's law see the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: @Matt: You're right about the quotes. It should work now, thanks for pointing these out.

Comment: for sure, good sticking up for your answer and making us think twice!  sorry for not reading more thoroughly the first time!